# QRCode scanner issue with react-native-camera

Tags: ios

I use ReactNative to develop my iOS APP,to realize the QRCode scanner function,i took the react-native-camera component which provide the barcode scanner function to my project.everything goes all right,but when i had succeed in recognizing a QRCode,next time i use the model,the screen just got frozen,seems like the app goes crashed.  something interesting that as the screen is frozen,and once the model cancelled from the left button of navigation,The module can work properly.
I'm not sure whether it's a inner bug of NavigatorIOS,or just the bug of react-native-camera itself.

here is the QRCode component code:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');

var {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  VibrationIOS,
  Navigator,
} = React;

var Camera = require('react-native-camera');


var { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

var QRCodeScreen = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    cancelButtonVisible: React.PropTypes.bool,
    cancelButtonTitle: React.PropTypes.string,
    onSucess: React.PropTypes.func,
    onCancel: React.PropTypes.func,
  },

  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      cancelButtonVisible: false,

      cancelButtonTitle: 'Cancel',
      barCodeFlag: true,
    };
  },

  _onPressCancel: function() {
    var $this = this;
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      $this.props.navigator.pop();
      if ($this.props.onCancel) {
       $this.props.onCancel();
      }
    });
  },

  _onBarCodeRead: function(result) {
    var $this = this;

    if (this.props.barCodeFlag) {
      this.props.barCodeFlag = false;

      setTimeout(function() {
        VibrationIOS.vibrate();
        $this.props.navigator.pop();

        $this.props.onSucess(result.data);
      }, 1000);
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    var cancelButton = null;

    if (this.props.cancelButtonVisible) {
      cancelButton = <CancelButton  onPress={this._onPressCancel} title={this.props.cancelButtonTitle} />;
    }

    return (
      <Camera onBarCodeRead={this._onBarCodeRead} style={styles.camera}>
        <View style={styles.rectangleContainer}>
          <View style={styles.rectangle}/>
        </View>
            {cancelButton}
      </Camera>
    );
  },
});

var CancelButton = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.cancelButton}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress}>
          <Text style={styles.cancelButtonText}>{this.props.title}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  },
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({

  camera: {
    width:width,
    height: height,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  rectangleContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },

  rectangle: {
    height: 250,
    width: 250,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#00FF00',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },


  cancelButton: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 3,
    padding: 15,
    width: 100,
    marginBottom: 10,

  },
  cancelButtonText: {
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: '#0097CE',
  },
});




module.exports = QRCodeScreen;
```

And In another Component I push this qrCode to the new sence:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  NavigatorIOS,
  AlertIOS,
  Navigator,
} = React;

var QRCodeScreen = require('./QRCodeScreen');

var cameraApp = React.createClass({
                                  render: function() {
                                  return (
                                          <NavigatorIOS
                                          style={styles.container}
                                          initialRoute={{
                                          title: 'Index',
                                          backButtonTitle: 'Back',
                                          component: Index,
                                          }}
                                          />

                                          );
                                  }
                                  });

var Index = React.createClass({

                              render: function() {
                              return (
                                      <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
                                      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressQRCode}>
                                      <Text>Read QRCode</Text>
                                      </TouchableOpacity>
                                      </View>
                                      );
                              },

                              _onPressQRCode: function() {
                              this.props.navigator.push({
                                                        component: QRCodeScreen,
                                                        title: 'QRCode',
                                                        passProps: {
                                                        onSucess:  this._onSucess,
                                                        },
                                                        });

                              },

//                              onPressCancel:function(){
//                              
//                              this.props.navigator.getContext(this).pop();
//                              
//                              },


                              _onSucess: function(result) {
                              AlertIOS.alert('Code Context', result, [{text: 'Cancel', onPress: ()=>console.log(result)}]);
                             // console.log(result);

                              },

                              });

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
                               container: {
                               flex: 1,
                               backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
                               },
                               contentContainer: {
                               flex: 1,
                               alignItems: 'center',
                               justifyContent: 'center',
                               }
                               });

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Example', () => cameraApp);
```

Any answer will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a inner bug of NavigatorIOS, or maybe just sth else wrong.

Blew is my code, it is ok.

```
'use strict';

const React = require('react-native');
const {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Navigator,
    } = React;

var QRCodeScreen = require('./QRCodeScreen');

const CameraApp = () => {
    const renderScene = (router, navigator) => {
        switch (router.name) {
            case 'Index':
                return <Index navigator={navigator}/>;
            case 'QRCodeScreen':
                return <QRCodeScreen
                    onSucess={router.onSucess}
                    cancelButtonVisible={router.cancelButtonVisibl}
                    navigator={navigator}
                    />;
        }
    }
    return (
        <Navigator
            style={styles.container}
            initialRoute={{
          name: 'Index',
        }}
            renderScene={renderScene}
            />
    );
};

const Index = ({navigator}) => {
    const onPressQRCode = () => {
        navigator.push({
            name: 'QRCodeScreen',
            title: 'QRCode',
            onSucess: onSucess,
            cancelButtonVisible: true,
        });
    };

    const onSucess = (result) => {
        console.log(result);
    };
    return (
        <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressQRCode}>
                <Text>Read QRCode</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
};

module.exports = CameraApp;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    contentContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try Library react native qrcode 
https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner. on me ,

its run. you can  try . in ios and android.